# PineScript, unable to get total active volume(volume which higher then 100m) for the pass 10 days

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to use pinescript to calculate the total active volume for the pass 10 days. Here i will consider active volume is above 100millions and i would like to filter out volume which less than 100 millions. Following are my code:

```
//@version=4
study("ActiveVol",overlay=false)
length = input(10,minval=10,title="Length")
var active_vol = 0

for i=0 to length
    if (volume[i] >= 1000000000)
        active_vol := active_vol + volume[i]

plot(active_vol);
```

it keep return the following error: line 11: Variable 'active_vol' was declared with 'integer' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[float]'.

May i know how can i resolve this problem? Million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following correction

```
var float active_vol = 0.0
```

Comment: ok, amended as commented and it's working

Comment: If the answer helped you, use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).